# Can i use custom certificate for iOS apps like APK's

Tags: android, ios, app-store-connect, sign

Like the title says, I would like to know if I can generate a private key myself (or one time download from Apple) to sign iOS apps before uploading to app store.

What I am trying to do is upload an app from a friends account to avoid paying the developer fee. He added me as admin, and I can publish as him but using my email.

In Android this is simple to do, I can simply use a private certificate and sign the apk, this way no one but me can release updates.

Is there a similar method for iOS apps for the Apple App Store?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question and explanation, I think the answer is no.

If you haven't got a signing certification you can not Upload to the AppStore, right?

There are 'other' tools to sign applications in order to make them work outside the AppStore, but I can not help with that.

What you are doing now is like be the owner of the development account, you have Admin privileges so you can control all the account, but the account can not be split in parts, it will work like one account only. There is no way to differentiate between your apps and your friend apps in the AppStore.

Comment: So the owner of the account owns all the certificates (and can generate new ones) to publish updates, and I am interested for Apple App store (edited question)

Comment: Yes, the admin is the master of the account, but Admin can generate user roles, like developer, marketing, finance, etc... each one has access to some parts of the account. Apple certificates do not work like Android ones. There are two kinds of certifications you need to install to upload the app to the store. These are provisioning profile, and development/distribution certs. provisioning profile is used to sign the app, certs are used to upload binaries to the account.